# Android Search Widget Custom Suggestion intent back to activity

Tags: android, listview, search

I've implemented a Custom Suggestions for my Search Widget based on [Custom Suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#IntentForSuggestions) based on [Searchable Dictionary](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html)

My searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:label="@string/app_label"
android:hint="@string/search_hint"
android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.worldclock.CitiesProvider"
android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.worldclock.CitiesProvider/cities" 
android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?">
</searchable>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <provider android:name="com.worldclock.CitiesProvider"
              android:authorities="com.worldclock.CitiesProvider" 
              android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.Intent.action.VIEW"/>
```

and I have a list activity where the search is originated. The tutorial states searchSuggestionIntentAction should be "android.Intent.action.VIEW" but I don't want to take the user to another activity like it does for Searchable Dictionary. All I want to do is add the suggested item (which I know the id of) at the bottom of my list without going though the activity life cycle. 
Currently it calls onCreate method of my list activity every time I pick a custom suggestion item from the search widget. I was wondering if that's possible not to refresh my list and just add an item to my adapter?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748898/use-the-searchdialog-intent-to-open-an-active-activity?rq=1)

should use `singleTop` mode and that solves my problems!

onNewIntent also needs to be implemented to handle the request!